# How to choose the best model from train/val loss and accuracy curves?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, caffe

In deep learning we should choose the best model according to the train/val loss and accuracy, but how do I know which point is the best?

Does it only depend on the val accuracy regardless of the other metrics?

And two more relevant questions:

How do the optimal train/val loss and accuracy curves look like?

What should I do if the train loss is decreasing and train accuracy is increasing, but the val loss is increasing while val accuracy stops increasing after training a long time?

It looks like this:

- [train accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MP4R.png)
- [train loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGwoR.png)
- [val accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Owr5k.png)
- [val loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuyGu.png)

Comment: Please provide more detail: What kind of data you are learning (images, sequences)? How many class you are trying to classify? Are the nhumber of samples balanced or imbalanced? What architecture you are using? What loss function you are using?

Comment: @FalconUA Thanks for response. My problem is to identify cloud from satellite images, so I transform the problem  to two classes segmentation,one is cloud,the other is background.The dataset have  8000 4-band-16bits images with size of 256*256.The architecture is Segnet, and the loss  function is binary_crossentropy. The samples are imbalanced since the cloud cover is relative small against the backgroud.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First in first, you need to choose model according to the result on development/validation dataset. Therefore, val accuracy and val loss are used to judge the model's performance.

To some extent, higher val accuracy are often associated with lower val loss. That's because your loss is used to measure the difference between the predicted result and the ground-truth.

Different problems measured by different metrics, just like we often use BLEU score in machine translation, you need to read some papers about your research field to get which metric is popular.

Train loss decrease and val loss increase is quite a normal apperance in model training, it usually means your model is over-fitting. It learns too much features only appeared in training dataset but not the whole dataset.

As for dealing with over-fitting, there are many methods like early-stopping, drop layers, etc. You can just google it.